# java "cannot find symbol" - how to import a file in the same directory?

Tags: java

I have two java files in a directory, neither of them are in a package. I want one of them to be able to reference the other. What is the right way to do this?

Currently in Class A, I'm trying to reference class B, and getting this error:

```
[javac] A.java:11: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : constructor B(java.lang.String)
[javac] location: class B
[javac]         B b = new B(path);
[javac]               ^
```

Nothing below worked:

- in A, doing "import B;"
- adding "package myPackage;" to both A and B

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your javac command line?

Comment: Could you post the code? There is a change you don't have a constructor that uses a String

Comment: With both classes in the same directory, both not declaring a package (i.e. both are in the default package) add the directory that contains your source files to the javac classpath.

Comment: In my case not found file just didn't have a `.java` extension (IDE didn't add it, as I expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post your code, so my answer may be wrong, but most likely you're trying to use a constructor in B which uses a string as parameter when there is none defined like that.

Here's my test:

```
class A {
    B b = new B("b");
}
class B {

}

$javac A.java 

A.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor B(java.lang.String)
location: class B
    B b = new B("b");
          ^
1 error
```

Looks the same doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you have a package reference in each file, you need to compile it from the root directory.  I had this same issue, hit this page, and none of the answers really helped.  So I have 2 files:

~/work/com/domain/pkg/library/A.java

~/work/com/domain/pkg/library/B.java

A.java:

```
package com.domain.pkg.library;

class A {
}
```

B.java:

```
package com.domain.pkg.library;

class B {
  A a = new A();
}
```

You need to be in ~/work and type:

```
javac com/domain/pkg/library/B.java
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have not setup your compilation dependency and classpath properly. If A needs B, you need to compile B first to get B.class and when you compile A, make sure B.class location is in your classpath so the compiler can find it.

Comment: As far as I know, javac will compile all dependent classes automatically.

Comment: @rsp you are right. It has been a while since I do manual command line compilation, I guess I remembering C compiler behavior :D